# Generalized commutator/anticommutator via phase factor

Tags: fermions, commutator, bosons, anyons, anticommutator

We know that the commutator between two operators $A$ and $B$ reads $[A,B]_{-}=AB - BA$, while the anticommutator reads $[A,B]_+=AB + BA$.

I am wondering if someone has ever used a generalized commutator $$[A,B]_{\theta}=AB + e^{-i\theta} BA$$

where with $\theta=\pi$ one has the commutator, while for $\theta=0$ one has the anticommutator.
If this exists, in what areas of physics has ever been used, and to do what?
Are there operators that commute with $\theta\neq 0$ and $\theta \neq \pi$?

Comment: The Abelian anyons appeared in level m Lauphlin states (FQHE) changes its phase by $e^{i2\pi/m}$ under particle permutation. Also, on the edge of FQHE, the excitations are described by level m chiral boson, whose vertex operators satisfy $[\psi(x),\psi(x')]_{2\pi/3}$ = 0.

Answer (score 4):

You bet. Heisenberg himself toyed with it (surprise!)-- see H. Rampacher, H. Stumpf, and F. Wagner, *Fortschr.d.Physik* **13** (1965) 385-480, (See Sec. III.9).

[Quantum algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_group) cover this area, and the deformed Heisenberg algebra you wrote was pioneered by Cigler in 1979 and underlies nonstandard quantum statistics, anyonic physics, and a plethora of physical systems.

You might enjoy 4.g. *et seq.* of a [brief 1990 review of mine](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/paradig.pdf) where several such "q-mutators" and their properties are discussed and correlated. A review you might enjoy is by [O W Greenberg 1993](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9301002) , the father of parastatistics.

The book by F Wilczek (1990) *Fractional Statistics and Anyon Superconductivity*  is a classic.

In fact, you may have several phases in your generalization to q-mutators, as explored by [me and Fairlie in 1991](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(91)90216-D).